# magento 2 - PayPal all in one not working

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express

I had Paypal all in one working just fine, and terms and conditions enabled (customer had to agree to the terms before making order).

suddenly I realized that agreeing the terms created an error with paypal so I canceled it, and even tried to switch to Paypal express checkout in order to fix it...

the issue now is when I try to make an order( in all in one ) I receive the following error:

> we can't initialize express checkout

and this is the exception:

```
[2017-11-22 17:25:08] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: we can't initialize express checkout Trace: #0 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/GetToken.php(126): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress->_initCheckout()
#1 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/Start.php(24): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\GetToken->getToken()
#2 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\Start->execute()
#3 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\Start\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\Start\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Express/Start/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\Start\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#7 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\Start\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#10 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#16 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#18 /chroot/home/minimoon/ochosbags.com/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#19 {main} [] []
```

looks like it is stuck on express checkout or something.

Is there a way to completely reset paypal module settings? or somehow fix it?

thanks a lot!

Comment: It has been fixed and re-occurred...
How can I debug this??